# Xamarin Android: Difference between GPSProvider and NetworkProvider

Tags: geolocation, xamarin.android, locationmanager

I am trying to get geolocation in my Xamarin Android app using LocationManager.

When i used GPSProvider as the location provider, OnLocationChanged didnt execute. Then i tried NetworkProvider and OnLocationChanged did executed and i could find the geo location.

What is the difference between GPSProvider and NetworkProvider and which will be more reliable?

Answer (score 1):

GPS might not have given you any location, because when you are indoors, the signal can go from very bad to unavailable. Use FusedLocation as it manages the providers and will use the one that gives the best location at any given time. If you are indoors, it will use the Networkprovider. If you are outdoors it will use the GPSProvider

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use FusedLocation (needs google play configuration) you can try GetBestProvider then the device will select the best provider for a criteria
Documentation and code sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/#GetBestProvider)